# Image of type byte[] is not returned when editing profile in asp.net core edit view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

When creating user profile I use

```html
<div id="Foto" class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="foto" id="labelFoto" class="control-label"></label>
    <input type="file" id="cargarFoto" asp-for="foto" onchange="readURL(this,$(document.getElementById('perfilFoto')));" />

    @if (Model.foto != null)
    {
        <img id="perfilFoto" src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.foto)" style="border:2px solid;max-height:100px; max-height:100px" />
    }
    else
    { 
        <img id="perfilFoto" style="border:2px solid;max-height:100px; max-height:100px" />
    }

    <span asp-validation-for="foto" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

The image is saved to the database.

But if I try to edit the profile in edit view when I reach to

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ID,nombre,apellido,tDocID,calle,altura,ciudad,provinciaID,Email,telefono,celular,clubID,foto")] EditPerfilViewModel perfil)
```

`foto` is not the original image but is null

Comment: Please check how to [upload the files in asp.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1) .

Comment: The problem is not uploading the image, when i create the profile i load the image via Iformfile and i save it to database correctly.

Comment: But when i try to edit the profile lets say to change phone number the image is shown in the edit view but is not returned in the POST so when the database is updated the image disapears